# Filtering a table from search word

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple table:

```
<Table bordered striped>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Requested By</th>
      <th>Approved By</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {accountList?.map((account, index) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{account.name}</td>
        <td>{account.status}</td>
        <td>
          {account.confirmDate == null
            ? ""
            : moment(account.confirmDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
        </td>
        <td>{account.requestedBy}</td>
        <td>{account.approvedBy}</td>
        <td style={{ width: 90 }} className={"text-center"}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faList}
            onClick={() => showAccountModal(account)}
          />{" "}
          {/* <FontAwesomeIcon                
      icon={faCreditCard}
      onClick={()=>showBankModal(account)}
    /> */}
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

And then i Have a free text search box. I would like to filter all accounts, where name contains the search word. I could fairly easy just have to hooks/variables with the full result in one variable and the filtered in another and then swap between the two. But is there something smarter in REACT? Some kind of filter pipe like Angular? I want to do all filtering client side.

Comment: Do you mean something like [array::filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? Filter data source *then* map to JSX? What have you tried? What isn't working? Is there an error?

Comment: No error. Looking for right approach. Would you just have to variables, one with all data and one with filtered data and the set those dependant whether the search box is empty?

Comment: No, you can filter your data in-line, with keeping only *an* extra filter value state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array::filter` and filter your state in-line right in the render logic.

```
({ name }) => !nameFilter || name.includes(nameFilter)
```

Returns true if the `nameFilter` is falsey (`''`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`) and short-circuit the boolean expression and so will return all elements, otherwise will continue evaluating the expression and process `name.includes(nameFilter)`.

Updated code

```
accountList?.filter(
  ({ name }) => !nameFilter || name.includes(nameFilter),
).map((account, index) => (...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an in-box solution use https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/filtering

But your approach is pretty simple: Store raw data (array) like the source of truth, filtered array store in local state.
Add a handler onChange to input something like this `setFilteredData(raw.filter(el => el.name.includes(name)))`